# Center group of columns in Foundation

Tags: html, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

Is there a way to center a group of uneven number of columns in a row in Foundation? Due to the unevenness, I don't see how this can be achieved with the offset option provided, since the offset would have to be a non-integer.

The image below explains what I'm trying to achieve. 6 single-column divs in total, where 5 of them are centered in the entire row, leaving an offset of 2.5 columns to the first column.

[image]

Comment: Can you just wrap all the center divs in another div and then just center that div? Or maybe you could up the number of columns...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is slightly unorthodox in Foundation terms, but your design requires an unorthodox solution.

First give the row a right padding of half a column's width in the CSS; 1 column = 8.3333% width, so this padding should be 4.1666%.

Next give the first column a right margin also of 4.1666%.

Now give the second column an offset of 2 columns, and you should be there (the last column will also need class end to make it left justify up against the previous column).

```
<div class="column first-column">...</div>
<div class="column large-1 large-offset-2">...</div>
...[other columns]...
<div class="column end">...</div>

.row { padding-right: 4.1666%; }
.first-column { margin-right: 4.1666%; !important}
```

You might possibly need !important on these unusual margins and paddings one (I can't remember offhand) to override Foundations setting of margin:0 on columns - try !important if these paddings and margins don't work without it). (NB: I am working from Foundation 5 basis, I didn't use the earlier versions).

Comment: Thanks, that would probably work. I will try to find a non-css way, and if I fail at that, I will accept your answer.